# iTunes Download Previous Purchase Fails

Tags: macos, itunes

I'm running iTunes 10.6 on OS X Lion 10.7.3.

I've tried multiple times to download this one song, and it keeps failing.  All other songs I've previously purchased downloaded with no problem the first time.  Here is the error:

[image]

And here is the view of the status in my downloads list:

[image]

I've tried closing iTunes and re-opening but the same error happens when I try to download again.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Where does your iTunes library live, on your main OSX drive or on another drive?

Comment: Main drive, only have one.

Answer (score 1):

Do you run any AntiVirus on your Mac?

Intego NetBarrier seems to be the culprit for a lot of people with the same issue.

There are similar reports of error -100000 on Windows as well and many of them were resolved by disabling Firewall and AntiVirus.